# REST Easy: No resource found error

Tags: java, rest, date, post, void

I want to use a Post on a resource in Java, but I get this error:

```
Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header
```

This is the method in my DAO that sets some date limits, that I have hard-coded for now:

```
public void setMonth(){
        Query query = e.createNativeQuery("Begin "
                + "scheme.table.Setlimits( TO_DATE( '2011/09', 'YYYY/MM'), TO_DATE( '2016/09', 'YYYY/MM'));"
                + "end;");      
    }
```

This is my resource:

```
 @POST
        @Path("setMonth")
        @Logging
        public void setMonthJSON() {
            sService.setMonth();
        }
```

and this is my service:

```
@Logging
     public void setMonth() {
        sDAO.setMonth();
     }
```

I have no idea what could be the problem... Does anybody have any ideas ?

Comment: Can you upvote and accept the answer if this has helped?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a GET on a Post?

```
 @POST
        @Path("setMonth")
        @Logging
        public void setMonthJSON() {
            sService.setMonth();
        }
```

A get will have @GET - pls review what you are trying to do? How are you calling the endpoint?

```
 @GET
        @Path("setMonth")
        @Logging
        public void setMonthJSON() {
            sService.setMonth();
        }
```

The browser will "always" issue a GET request for your resource. You can either use curl or plugin which can make post request from browser like Postman for Chrome or RESTEasy or RESTClient for firefox.

Comment: I am trying to use a @POST, as you can see from my code.. Is it possible that it looks up for some other path ?

Comment: How are you calling - curl command, browser request or some other tool? The browser will issue a GET request for your resource - which you have declared as a PUT on the server-side The request you have is trying to 'fetch' (or GET) the resource and nothing or no mapping exists for GET.

Comment: I am calling by browser request.

Comment: As I said the browser will "always" issue a GET request for your resource. You can either use curl or plugin which can make post request from browser like Postman for Chrome or RESTEasy or RESTClient for firefox.

Comment: ok. I am using postman and it does not give me any error. Do you have any idea how can I check if my call was made, because it does not return any results sets or anything

Comment: put a debugger in your code and see what was called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123683/discussion-between-sheetal-mohan-sharma-and-blaa).